# wpf Dependency property before changing event?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a dependency property on a control which is a custom class.

Now is there an event that gets raised BEFORE the value is being changed?

I know that OnPropertyChanged is raised after the property has already changed.

I need some event before so that I can cancel the changing....in order to preserve the state of the control.

I cannot set back the dependency property back to its old value as that will mean that I lose state in the control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If its your `DependencyProperty`, you can use the [ValidateValueCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.validatevaluecallback.aspx) to validate the incoming value and reject it, if its not as you desire.

In the following example, only values greater than 0 will be accepted:

```
public int Test {
    get { return (int)GetValue(TestProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
}


public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(int), typeof(YourClass), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(0), delegate(object v) { 
      return ((int)v) > 0; // Here you can check the value set to the dp
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data objects implement INotifyPropertyChanging, then you can handle the PropertyChanging event which is raised before the property value changes.

INotifyPropertyChanging was introduced in .NET 3.5

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys!

Answer (score -1):

You may check value of property in property declaration set section. Suppose we have CustomColor dep property:

```
public Color CustomColor
{
   get { return GetValue(CustomColorProperty) as Color;}

   set 
   { 
      //check value before setting
      SetValue(CustomColorProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Also there will be helpfull for you [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx), [ValidateValueCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.validatevaluecallback.aspx), [CoerceValueCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.coercevaluecallback.aspx) delegates.

Comment: It is not recommended to have any logic inside the getter/setter for a dependency property because the binding engine does not actually end up using them.